# IntelliJ is not opening after a memory problem

Tags: intellij-idea, while-loop, jetbrains-ide

I ran a while true loop and my IntelliJ got stuck forever.

I restarted my computer, uninstalled and installed IntelliJ and it is still stuck with the logo of IntelliJ on the screen and that's it, it doesn't work at all and I can't see my code.

Any advices?